# Cannot Implement TagEntry in xamarin forms

Tags: tags, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement the TagEntry in Xamarin.Forms but I'm unable to do it. Please can someone redirect me to the right place? Or if there is any other way we can do that in Xamarin Forms. Anything like this will be of great help.

GitHub: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/TagEntryView

[image]

Things I've done till now

1. Replicated the entire code in my code.
2. on the xaml I;ve added a the control of type TagEntryView

   using App1.Controls;
   using NokariMahamandal.Models;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   using Xamarin.Forms;

   namespace App1.View
   {
       public partial class Services : ContentPage
       {
          public Candidate candidate { get; set; }
           public ObservableCollection skills = new ObservableCollection();

   ```
       public Services()
       {
           skills.Add("Samples");
           skills.Add("Samples2");
           Bar.TagItems = skills;
           InitializeComponent();

       }
       public Services(Candidate cand)
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           candidate = cand;
           var foo = new TagEntryView();
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Xaml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:dltoolkit="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.TagEntryView"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:App1.Controls; assebmly=App1"
             x:Class="App1.View.Services">
  <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout>
        <uc:TagEntryView x:Name="Bar" TagItems="{Binding ConnectionType}" Text="Sample"></uc:TagEntryView>
      </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I've tried following

Comment: <StackLayout>
        <uc:TagEntryView x:Name="Bar" TagItems="{Binding ConnectionType}" Placeholder="Sample text here!" ></uc:TagEntryView>
      </StackLayout>


in code behind

  Bar.TagEntry.Text = "Sample";

Comment: I think you could better update your question

Comment: Thanks will do. However I'm not sure what to do next. @GeraldVersluis can you guide me?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Please check the code that I've added and let me know what i need to do next.

Comment: You need to add the part of your code you need help with specifically

Comment: @EstebanVerbel please check. I'm not able to see anything in the running state.

Comment: @AkshayHalasangi Did you ever get this working? I'm currently trying to get it to work and am quite stuck. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Look at older (deleted) samples: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/646c93a35f9d9d636cd672b23d7076c6e21a4888/Examples/ExamplesTagEntryView